# Как сделать список внутри элемента списка RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, нужно сделать список внутри элемента списка RecyclerView. Длина списка который внутри элемента всегда разная и неизвестна. Если использовать TextView.append то при пролистывания списка (кажется обновляются элементы влезающие в экран) получаются лишние строки. Есть какой-нибудь способ?

Comment: Вам прямо список в списке или надо просто размер ячейки менять? Может ваша проблема в сохранении состояния изменяемой ячейки при скроле?

Comment: Необходимо вопрос уточнить, append не сделает скролл внутри списка. Да и поверьте если вы делаете вертикальный скролл внутри вертикального списка, то самое время задуматься о правильной структуре view и почитать material guidline, так делать очень не рекомендуется.

Comment: второй список не нужно пролистывать, он должен отображаться как элемент списка recyclerView, в итоге я сделал через .append но как мне кажется это не идеальное решение
сохранение состояния тоже добился

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй использовать библиотеку https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view